# Unity Google Cardboard persistence

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have two scenes in my Unity 5.1 project. The first does not have any cardboard reference in it, it's a Vuforia AR scene. When I click on an object it loads the second scene.

In the second scene I use the cardboard SDK to track the device rotation. I don't need stereo. I only use these commands:

```
Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled = false
Cardboard.SDK.UpdateState();
Cardboard.SDK.HeadPose.Orientation;
```

The problem occurs when I load the first scene back after the second scene. It seems that the Cardboard SDK persists and it hides the AR Camera. I get a black screen instead of the camera view.

I tried putting

```
  Cardboard.SDK.VRModeEnabled       = false;
  Cardboard.SDK.EnableSettingsButton    = false;
  Cardboard.SDK.EnableAlignmentMarker = false;
  Cardboard.SDK.enabled = false;
```

before leaving the second scene, and at the start of the first scene, to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated,
Nir.

Comment: Or, in shorter words: Can I disable the Cardboard SDK?

Comment: are you observing any Game object (a prefab of Cardboard) created automatically in your first scene ??

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be fixed in the latest version (0.5.1) of the Cardboard SDK.

Another way to tackle it (if you don't want to upgrade, or it is still a problem) is to add a Cardboard script to an object in the first scene, and set its "VRModeEnabled" property to false.

Answer (score 0):

There is a guide at the Vuforia site for transitioning between mono and stereo:

https://developer.vuforia.com/library/articles/Solution/Implementing-a-Mono-to-Stereo-Transition-for-Cardboard-Apps